# Reconciling the slight difference between a 2-variable equation and a 3-variable equation

Tags: vector-analysis, tangent-line

I am studying gradients right now and how they relate to tangent planes of a graph.

I came across how you can get a tangent curve of $z=f(x,y)$ if you define it as a level curve at $0$ for the function $F(x,y,z) = f(x,y) - z = 0$.

I came across this problem:

**Find the tangent plane  for $2z-x^2=0$ at $P_0(2,0,2)$**

If we say that $F(x,y,z) = 2z-x^2$, then the gradient would be $\nabla{F} = -4i+2k$

Evaluating the the dot product, the tangent plane is $-4(x-2)+2(z-2)=0$ which is $2z-4x+4=0$.

Now say that $f(x,z) = y = 2z-x^2$. Then the gradient evaluated at $P_0(2,0,2)$ is $\nabla{f = -4i-j+2k}$. As a result, the tangent line is $-4(x-2) -(y-0)+2(z-2)=0$ which is $2z - 4x + 4= y$

**EDIT** I forgot to mention that if $f(x,z) = y$, we can define $F(x,y,z) = 2z-x^2 - f(x,y)$ for the level curve $F(x,y,z)=0$.

We then have:

$$2z-4x+4=0$$
$$2z - 4x + 4= y$$

While the first only allows $z$ and $x$ to be certain values with a free range $y$, the second one allows both $z$ and $x$ to be any value.

How can this be so?

Comment: The first one is correct.  In the second equation, you are putting $f(x,z)=y$ which is not in the original equation.